# Why does this unit test fail? (Promises with Jasmine/AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-strap

Unit test for a directive, where escope is the scope isolated

I have also tried pulling in $rootScope with $rootScope.$apply() and
$rootScope.$digest() init_data() is not being called from the unit test though :(((. The modal is an angularStrap modal.

```
it('should open the dialog', function(){
    spyOn(escope.mainModal.$promise, "then").and.callFake(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

         deferred.resolve(true);

        return deferred.promise;
    });

    spyOn(escope, 'init_data');

    escope.openDialog();
    escope.$apply();
    expect(escope.mainModal.$promise.then).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(escope.init_data).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And in the directive..

```
$scope.openDialog = function() {

    $scope.mainModal.$promise.then(function(f) {
        debugger
        $scope.init_data();

    });

}
```

The first spy passes, but the init_data spy fails. For the life of me I can't figure this out.

Comment: What happens if you take the `debugger` call out of your code?

Comment: Still fails. I put the debugger in to see if the promise was resolving. It wasn't :(

Answer (score 0):

So the real problem is that the modal's $promise is an object rather than a function call, which spy is expecting.

Here is the refactor that "fixed" the test.

```
it('should open the dialog', function(){

    spyOn(escope, "getModal").and.returnValue($q.when({}));
    spyOn(escope, 'init_data');

    escope.openDialog();
    escope.$apply();

    expect(escope.init_data).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And the directive was changed like so:

```
$scope.getModal = function(){
    return $scope.mainModal.$promise;
}

$scope.openDialog = function() {

    $scope.getModal().then(function(f) {

        $scope.init_data();

    });

}
```